# How historically accurate are the Assassin's Creed games?

Tags: crusades, american-revolution, pope

I've been highly entertained recently watching youtube videos of a game series called Assassin's Creed. It tells the story of a family who are members of a Order (called Assasins) who have waged a war with another group (Templars) for hundreds of years. Each game seems fixed on one member of the family in a specific time period. The first one was set during the Crusades of the England's Richard, the second one during the rise of the Borgia family in Italy and then recently in America before and during the Revolution. During these stories they interact with many historical events and figures.

For those familiar with these games, are the portrayals accurate?

Comment: No, they are not accurate. Listing inaccuracies is likely to be "too broad". Listing accuracies is probably easier. besides, you can already find a lot on this subject by a quick internet search.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a game, and not about historical facts (except as they may be "incidental" to the game).

Comment: IMO the main problem with this question **obviously** isn't that "it is about a game", but that it shows no research effort. And a secondary problem, as @LennartRegebro pointed out, _might_ be the broad scope (though I'm not entirely sure about that).

Answer (score 5):

I found a few articles, [here](http://www.1up.com/features/assassins-creed-historical-inaccuracies) and [here](http://www.hbhud.com/2012/04/05/historical-accuracy-of-video-games-assassins-creeds-al-mualim/). The historical inaccuracies are quite extensive, ranging from anachronisms like tomatoes, to conspiracy theories regarding the knights templar.